# I'm make a discord bot and i need to make command to delete all user from database I'm use MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, discord, discord.js

I'm try this but this delete only one user i need to delete all users on the database

```
JailSchema.findOneAndDelete(
  {
    guildId: interaction.guild.id,
  },
  (err, res) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log("Done");
  }
);
```

Comment: Perhaps use `deleteMany` instead of `findOneAndDelete`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a mongoose function literally called `findOneAndDelete`, instead use the `deleteMany` function and give it the same identifier, should work the same but it won't limit itself to 1.